# How to compile alljoyn sdk alljoyn-16.04a-src for ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, alljoyn

I want to compile sample template file alljoyn sdk alljoyn-16.04a-src for ios but getting file missing error (alljoyn/Status.h file not found.)
There is no sample file like AllJoynChat xcodeproj to compile for ios sdk alljoyn 16 version.
I am not able to compile any sample code provided with this latest sdk for ios. [image]

Comment: I have followed step by step procedures described here https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/api-guide/core/objc#
except open ssl set up because in the latest alljoyn-16.04a-src version open ssl dependencies has been removed. But still getting file missing error.

Comment: that link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

AllJoyn iOS Project template is deprecated and has been removed from 16.10 release.

To build other samples, make sure that you have built AllJoyn Framework. You can do it using alljoyn_darwin Xcode project. 
More details in section "Building the AllJoyn Framework -> Xcode IDE build" here: https://allseenalliance.org/framework/documentation/develop/building/ios-osx/build-source

For different devices you need to build corresponding targets: for example for iOS simulators higher than iPhone 6, you need to build alljoyn_core_ios_x64 target.

Comment: that link is broken.